# Symfony 4.2 Custom Circular Reference Handler Does not Apply

Tags: config, normalization, circular-reference, symfony-4.2

The context is that I have been trying to set up a Custom Circular Reference Handler for my entities that will effect ALL entities.

According to documentation ( https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references ), we are guided to set the `circular_reference_handler` value under the `serializer` service in the `config/packages/framework.yaml` file as such:

```
framework:
    validation:
        enabled: true

    messenger:
        enabled: true

    assets:
        enabled: true

    serializer:
        circular_reference_handler: App\Services\CircularReferenceHandler
        enable_annotations: true
```

My actual problem is that when the serializer attempts to load the circular reference handler my override doesn't seem to exist: 
[image showing key referenced](https://ibb.co/KGp92MS)
[image showing context empty](https://ibb.co/B4gdJhy)

Why isn't my override getting applied to the context at all??

I have attempted to:

- Reload cache
- Use a ContextBuilder class from my API Platform package
- Apply it in a Normalizer

None of have worked

I showed you my yaml, but here is the handler:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class CircularReferenceHandler
{
    /**
     * @param object $object
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __invoke($object)
    {
        return $object->getId();
    }
}
```

and here is the Context builder I attempted to use as an alternative:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Serializer;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Serializer\SerializerContextBuilderInterface;
use App\Services\CircularReferenceHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer;

final class GlobalSerializerContextBuilder implements SerializerContextBuilderInterface
{
    /**
     * Creates a serialization context from a Request.
     *
     * @param Request    $request
     * @param bool       $normalization
     * @param array|null $extractedAttributes
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function createFromRequest(Request $request, bool $normalization, array $extractedAttributes = null): array
    {
        $resourceClass = $context['resource_class'] ?? null;

        $context[AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER] = CircularReferenceHandler::class;

        return $context;
    }
}
```

and here is where I registered that ( [doc](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#changing-the-serialization-context-dynamically) ):

```
    App\Serializer\GlobalSerializerContextBuilder:
        decorates: 'api_platform.serializer.context_builder'
        arguments: ['@App\Serializer\GlobalSerializerContextBuilder.inner']
        autoconfigure: false
```

**I expected** my custom circular_reference_handler to be applied when the `AbstractNormalizer->handleCircularReference()` method is used, **but the actuality** is the context received in this method does not include my additional key/value pair ( e.g. `['circular_reference_handler => App\Services\CircularReferenceHandler]`

Answer (score 2):

So I found that I must have made a mistake when I was using the Normalizer strategy. Essentially, if you want to globally change the serializer `$context` ( 3rd param in SerializerInterface->serialize($data, $format, ***array $context = []***) ), then you should create a custom ***Symfony*** Normalizer.

Here is my final class:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Serializer;

use App\Services\CircularReferenceHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

/**
 * Class ApiNormalizer. Acts as an entrypoint to GLOBALLY alter context for all denormalizers and normalizers ( and subsequenty the serializers ).
 * @package App\Serializer
 */
final class ApiNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, DenormalizerInterface
{
    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $normalizer)
    {
        if (!$normalizer instanceof DenormalizerInterface) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The normalizer must implement the DenormalizerInterface');
        }

        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
    }

    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $this->normalizer->denormalize($data, $class, $format, $context);
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->normalizer->supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format);
    }

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $context[AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER] = CircularReferenceHandler::class;
        $context['enable_max_depth'] = true;

        return $this->normalizer->normalize($object, $format, $context);
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->normalizer->supportsNormalization($data, $format);
    }
}
```

The method to look at is just `normalize()`. That's the only place I needed to make a change as of now and the interface required that I stub out the rest of the methods at the very least so you can ignore the others. However, now I have a place where I can globally alter the data or state of the serialization context whenever I have the need.

Hope this helps someone else.